# Need to set a array string length so that it is exactly 13

Tags: c++

hi there i'm currently finishing a project at college but need to set a length of 13 to a string so that it will return an error message if it is shorter or longer than 13 my code so far is

```
 void add_new_text_book()
 {
//this option is here to add a new book to the list
printf("Please enter the Title of a new text book\n");
scanf("%s",book[number_of_books].title);
printf("Please enter the Authors firstname\n");
scanf("%s",book[number_of_books].firstname);
printf("Please enter the Author surname\n");
scanf("%s",book[number_of_books].surname);

printf("Finally please enter the ISBN number of the book\n");
scanf("%s",book[number_of_books].isbn);

if(length_of_string==13)//will be used to check the length of the book is valid

{
    if(number_of_books==15)//will check to see how many records have been used
    {
    printf("book not added as you have used all free space\n");
    }else
    {
    printf("Book has been added to the libary\n");
    number_of_books=number_of_books+1;
    }

}else{
printf("You have entered too many or few characters the books has not been saved\n");
}

getch();
    length_of_string=strlen(book[number_of_books].isbn);
```

but even when i enter 13 it comes up with the error message it only seems to accept 123-456-789-1 any help will be greatly accepted

Comment: Can you show the code that calculates `length_of_string`?

Comment: What is your string? `std::string`? `char` array?

Comment: length_of_string=strlen(book[number_of_books].isbn);

Comment: @ScottLWalker How can you obtain the [`strlen`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=strlen&aq=f&oq=strlen&aqs=chrome.0.57j65j0l3j62.2994j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) from the string in struct even before you assign any data in it? (I hope you are not doing that). From your code, number_of_books will point to the previously entered book. and not the recentmost entry. So `strlen ()` will return the length of previously entered book.which can be `0` for the 1st entry,incase you initialsed number_of_books as 0 in the beginning

Comment: @ScottLWalker Post some more code, I think you have messed up witht the initialisation part

Comment: it sits just bellow the getch this isn't in the main part its in add_a_new_book which is part of my project this is the only part that dosn't work form that

Comment: thats the full part of the program

Comment: @ScottLWalker If your line `length_of_string=strlen(book[number_of_books].isbn);` is below the `getch` line the code won't work. Move it before the `if` block.

Comment: @ScottLWalker  Try adding a print statement when you accept or reject a value so that you can display the string and the string length so you can figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: thanks @SuvP it worked perfectly now sorry to everyone but thank you for taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help considerably if you calculated `length_of_string` before you used it, rather than after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.size() to do your calculations.

Taken from C++ reference

```
// string::size
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
std::string str ("Test string");
std::cout << "The size of str is " << str.size() << " characters.\n";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what the value of "length_of_string" ?
is its value is :123-456-789-1? 
if so you can use it :

```
if(length_of_string.size()==13)//will be used to check the length of the book is valid


 {
    if(number_of_books.size()==15)//will check to see how many records have been used

 {
    printf("book not added as you have used all free space\n");

  }else

 {
    printf("Book has been added to the libary\n");
    number_of_books=number_of_books+1;

  }

  }
else

    {
  printf("You have entered too many or few characters the books has not been saved\n");

     }

getch();

   }
```

Comment: hi no its length_of_string=strlen(book[number_of_books].isbn); thats what i'm trying to set the length of

Comment: you can get string length by using book[number_of_books].isbn.size() for more information :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/